# How to force scrollbars on child div when parent has relative height?

Tags: html, css, scroll

The problem I'm trying to solve is quite simple, yet I find hard to achieve what I want using my CSS techniques.

What I want is to have some sort of parent `div` with height set to relative value (like: 100% or 30%). Please do not ask why do I need it, as this is simply a partial and explaining whole layout goes beyond this question.

Inside this parent, I need to have a header `h1` followed by child `div` containing lots of text. **And the most important**, I need to have scrollbars only inside child div, so that the header will always stay attached to the top of container.

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum (... lots of text)
    </div>
</div>
```

(NOT)Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CodeConstructors/BEVSS/

Comment: I think your fiddle link might be broken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y77g/12/) something you want to achieve?
**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="header">
          HEADER
     </div>
     <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum (... lots of text)
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fec;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}
.content {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    top: 40px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: The effect looks good. I'll try to put it into my context and see if it works equally good

Comment: Yup, it works. I'm sure I tried it before, but perhaps something else in my layout was causing this to fail. Last week was a looong week :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 properties calc(),like this:

```
html, body { height: 100% }
.wrapper {
    height: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
h1 {height: 20px}
.text { 
  overflow: auto; 
  height:-webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
  height: -moz-cale(100% - 20px);
  height: -ms-cale(100% - 20px);
  height: -o-cale(100% - 20px);
  height: cale(100% - 20px);
}
```

you need define the heading's height.
The [DEMO](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/lxjcI).If you want to know the calc () method of use, you can click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css3/how-to-use-css3-calc-function.html).

Comment: The other response was more accurate, but +1 for CALC solution! Nice!